# Wrong output in a c program

Tags: c, function, calling-convention

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a=1;
printf("%d%d%d",a,++a,a++);

}
```

Here why is the output 331 and not 122.

The reason i found on internet was that arguements are passed grom right to left . First a++ then ++a then a gets evaluated and then get printed in the reverse order. Is it the right reason.

Comment: no tell me the reason

Comment: Reason -Undefined Behaviour

Comment: @ cool guybut my book says it has something to do with calling convention

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4177063/2436655).

Comment: Calling convention indicates the order in which arguments are passed to a function when a function call is encountered. There are two possibilities here:
(a)
(b)
Arguments might be passed from left to right.
Arguments might be passed from right to left.
C language follows the second order.

Comment: this is written in my book

Comment: more over i find it right bcoz if u go from right to left output will be 331

Comment: Your book is wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: why if u go from right to left o/p is 331

Comment: Read the link posted as the second answer to the question n.m. linked to: http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html It's the only valid answer here.

Answer (score -1):

gcc -S your_source.c explain your question

```
    movl    $1, -4(%rbp)    #, a
    movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx  # a, a.0
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)    #, a
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)    #, a
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx  # a, tmp61
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # a, tmp62
    movl    %eax, %esi      # tmp62,
    movl    $.LC0, %edi     #, offset to "%d%d%d" sttring
    movl    $0, %eax        #,
    call    printf  #
```

compiler developer must not expect that someone will try to use it in such an ugly way

if you really need 122: then change asm code as follow:

```
    movl    $1, -4(%rbp)    #, a
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # a, a.0
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)    #, a
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx  # a, tmp61
    movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx  # a, tmp62
    movl    %eax, %esi      # tmp62,
    movl    $.LC0, %edi     #,
    movl    $0, %eax        #,
    call    printf  #
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)    #, a
    leave
```